# How to read text file lines after Specific lines using StreamReader

Tags: c#, string, io, text-files, streamreader

I have a text file which i am reading using StreamReader .Now as per my requirement whatever lines i have read first,i dont want to read again means i dont want to take that data again.So  i have added `File.ReadLines(FileToCopy).Count();` code to get the number of lines read at first.Now whatever line returned by above line of code,i want to read after that.
Here is my code .

```
        string FileToCopy = "E:\\vikas\\call.txt";

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(FileToCopy) == true)
        {

            lineCount = File.ReadLines(FileToCopy).Count();

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FileToCopy))
            {

            }
         }
```

What Condition i need to specify here .Please help me.

```
       while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {

            var nextLines = File.ReadLines(FileToCopy).Skip(lineCount);

        if (line != "")
        {
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a much faster way to do this that doesn't require you to read the entire file in order to get to the point where you left off. The key is to keep track of the file's length. Then you open the file as a `FileStream`, position to the previous length (i.e. the end of where you read before), and then create a `StreamReader`. So it looks like this:

```
long previousLength = 0;
```

Then, when you want to copy new stuff:

```
using (var fs = File.OpenRead(FileToCopy))
{
    // position to just beyond where you read before
    fs.Position = previousLength;

    // and update the length for next time
    previousLength = fs.Length;

    // now open a StreamReader and read
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(fs))
    {
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = sr.ReadLine();
            // do something with the line
        }
    }
}
```

This will save you *huge* amounts of time if the file gets large. For example if the file was a gigabyte in size the last time you read it, then `File.ReadLines(filename).Skip(count)` will take you 20 seconds to get to the end so you can read the next lines. The method I described above will take much less time--probably less than a second.

Comment: Downvoter? It's customary to leave a comment explaining why you think this answer isn't useful.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
lineCount = File.ReadLines(FileToCopy).Count();
```

Will return total lines count in your file.It's useless for you.You need to store the line count that you read from the file.Then everytime you read again, use `Skip` method:

```
var nextLines = File.ReadLines("filaPath").Skip(lineCount);
```

You don't need `StreamReader` here.For example if you read file for first time,let's say `10` line:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(filePath).Take(10);
lineCount += 10;
```

For second time `Skip` the first `10` line and read more and update the `lineCount`:

```
var nextLines = File.ReadLines(filePath).Skip(lineCount).Take(20);

lineCount += 20;
```

More generically you can write a method for this and call it whenever you want to read next lines:

```
public  static string[] ReadFromFile(string filePath, int count, ref int lineCount)
{
    lineCount += count;
    return File.ReadLines(filePath).Skip(lineCount).Take(count).ToArray();
}

private static int lineCount = 0;
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
   // read first ten line
   string[] lines = ReadFromFile("sample.txt", 10, ref lineCount);

   // read next 30 lines
   string[] otherLines = ReadFromFile("sample.txt", 30, ref lineCount)
}
```

I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Sir i tried but not able to get in my condition .Please see my updated post with code

Comment: Sir i have to read line by line and cant enter int count as dont know how many new lines has been added

Comment: If you mean that new lines are being _inserted_ at the beginning of the file, then you are going to have no choice but to remember details of those lines, and skip one-by-one as you recognize likeness.  Very complicated, and unlikely to be reliable.  Only a file that is being _appended to_ will be easy to read in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Just read `lineCount` lines from your new stream:

```
for(int n=0; n<lineCount; n++) 
{
    reader.ReadLine();
}
```

That is the easiest method, when you have to actually skip N lines (not N bytes).